# Select records where date field value is not in the current month and year

Tags: mysql

Trying to get records where a date in a datetime field is not within the current month and year.

I add the current date when an email is sent to the nl_last_sent field.

The script runs daily (emails a monthly newsletter) and I don't want to re-send the email to recipients that have already received it.

Since people can opt-in at any time during the month, I still want them to receive it during the current month, which is why I run it daily.

So if the value of nl_last_sent is 2019-03-07 8:55:10, they have already received the March 2019 newsletter.

And when I run again, I do not want that record included.

Testing with any date in 2019-03.. does not select the record. Correct.

I tested the code below, changing nl_last_sent to 2019-01-01 11:15:56, which should select the record since the year and month in the field do not match the current year and month, but no errors and no records returned.

```
... WHERE
( YEAR(nl_last_sent) != YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND MONTH(nl_last_sent) != MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You could try a rewrite `WHERE nl_last_sent NOT BETWEEN (LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())`   .. `(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` gets the starting day of the month

Answer (score 0):

@Raymond Nijland I will provide an MCVE next time, thanks!

Using a modified version of code from @Raymond Nijland , I was able to correct. Thanks for the assistance.

Final working code:

```
BETWEEN ( LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() ) + INTERVAL 1 DAY ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND 
LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() )
```